# Ender 3 - Prints above bed, but the purge/start line is perfect

Tags: creality-ender-3

I'm trying to print after letting the printer taking a break for a few months. Haven't touched anything, but it starts with the purge/start line and it looks good. When it tries to print my model the nozzle is 1 mm above the bed. Tried with both pla/petg, different Cura slicer configs (both default and CHEPs) but nothing makes any difference. Have anyone experience this?

Picture of the purge/start layer, looks ok:

[image]

This is when it starts printing the rest, you can see that the nozzle is a few milimeters above the bed:

[image]

I've tried level the bed (with the bed and nozzle heated) but does not help.

First 50 lines of G-code:

```
;FLAVOR:Marlin
;TIME:3655
;Filament used: 3.24955m
;Layer height: 0.28
;MINX:93.425
;MINY:80.447
;MINZ:0.28
;MAXX:141.575
;MAXY:154.549
;MAXZ:7
;Generated with Cura_SteamEngine 5.2.1
M140 S50
M105
M190 S50
M104 S200
M105
M109 S200
M82 ;absolute extrusion mode
; Ender 3 Custom Start G-code
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G28 ; Home all axes
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X0.1 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to start position
G1 X0.1 Y200.0 Z0.3 F1500.0 E15 ; Draw the first line
G1 X0.4 Y200.0 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to side a little
G1 X0.4 Y20 Z0.3 F1500.0 E30 ; Draw the second line
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X5 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move over to prevent blob squish
G92 E0
G92 E0
G1 F2700 E-5
;LAYER_COUNT:25
;LAYER:0
M107
;MESH:Bodacious Lappi (2).stl
G0 F6000 X98.561 Y101.407 Z0.28
;TYPE:WALL-INNER
G1 F2700 E0
G1 F1073.8 X98.219 Y101.649 E0.0218
G1 F926.6 X96.942 Y101.649 E0.0988
G1 F848.1 X95.665 Y101.65 E0.18294
G1 F969.7 X95.231 Y101.371 E0.21267
G1 F1200 X95.065 Y101.043 E0.22979
G1 X95.065 Y95.95 E0.46694
G1 X95.231 Y95.534 E0.4878
G1 F1073.8 X95.596 Y95.255 E0.51171
G1 F924.9 X96.873 Y95.255 E0.58886
G1 F846.6 X98.15 Y95.256 E0.67315
G1 F969.7 X98.557 Y95.495 E0.70034
```

Comment: Weird. The initial line is extruded at Z=0.3 while the first layer starts on Z=0.28 and the only non-motion things that happen is switching the blower off, and messing with extrusion parameters. I really can't tell what is wrong, but it's definitely none of the trivial stuff. ...Put M90 before M82 in the startup G-code. Not sure if it will help, but worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

The default purge line is supposed to be **thick**. So thick that it's actually problematic for some materials. Thus, it's possible for it to come out "thin but adhering to the bed just fine" if your distance from the nozzle to the bed is significantly too high. You probably just need to adjust your bed height.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you fixed it yet but this happened to me today. There's an eccentric nut on the right. Tighten it so it doesn't wobble but not so tight that it doesn't move.